# Can't get optional parameters to work with mvn eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I created a `mvn` build with the goal set as `dependency:list`

I want to see file sizes, so I tried passing in `depedency:list -Darguments=-DdependencyDetailsEnabled=true`

also 
`depedency:list -DdependencyDetailsEnabled=true`

and lastly I did `dependency:list` and added a parameter called `dependencyDetailsEnabled` with value of true

none of these displayed file size for the dependencies. My wish is to see total file size of all maven dependencies for a project, but I can only find that I can list per jar with the above command, and even that is not working.

Comment: I see no indication that there is any [supported option](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html) called "dependencyDetailsEnabled" or anything like that. Why do you think this option will do something? Also, please state what version of maven and what version of maven-dependency-plugin you are using

Comment: sorry looks like I was looking at the wrong maven command. I know we use maven 2.0.11, I think plugin is 1.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for the [Maven Project Info Reports](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/dependencies-mojo.html) plugin. Running this as

```
mvn -DdependencyDetailsEnabled=true project-info-reports:dependencies
```

will create a dependency report with file sizes (as well as other metrics). You'll need version 2.1 (or later) of the plugin.

Cheers,

Comment: thanks, this actually didnt work, I changed it up and found it out wouldn't work no matter what because I don't have the correct version :(